# Treat String as JavaScript and output variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have string '${hello} ${love} times' 
I would like to replace hello by the variable named hello and love by the variable named love without removing times. I am using ReactJS with JSX.
My attempt is just removing the $, { and } from the string and then deal with it.

```
var cut = this.props.string.split(" ");
var one = cut[0].split("{");
var two = one[1].split("}");
var thin = this.var[two[0]];
```

and then use thin

Comment: Please provide your attempt.

Comment: @Lexi it's really robust.

Comment: Why not just use ES6 and string interpolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is completely unclear... Do you know how ES6 template literals work? You have to use **backticks** to enable string interpolation, not regular quotes (`''` or `""`).

Is this what you are trying to do?

```js
let hello = 'Hello',
    love = 'LOVE';

console.log(`${hello} ${love} times`);
```

Comment: what if the template literals are saved in a variable?

Comment: It should work too. Template literals are like regular strings but with interpolation and multiline support.

Comment: so if i pass the string "${hello} ${love} times" (taken from a database for example) as props how will I use it with the variables hello and love?